# Step Counter Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement a step counter in my sprite Kit game.

And it should work like this:

1. The counter adds 1 to a value each second.
2. Every fifth second the duration (in this case 1) gets divided by 1.1

But if I create a func that returns the new duration, the repeat forever SKAction only uses this value for one time and then the duration never changes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make an action that calls itself, rather than using `SKAction.repeatForever(...)`. you can recalculate values that way. not sure i entirely understand your use case, but here is an example that fires an event after a duration, and modifies that duration every fifth cycle.

```
var isLoopEnabled:Bool = true
var counter:Int = 0
var duration:TimeInterval = 1.0
func updateDuration() {
    duration /= 1.1
}

/*
 creates an event loop. the action waits, fires, then calls itself again (before exiting)
 turn the loop off using the isLoopEnabled flag
 */
func loop() {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
    
    let run = SKAction.run { 
        self.counter += 1 //increment counter
        
        //update duration every fifth count
        if self.counter % 5 == 0 {
            self.updateDuration()
        }
    }
    
    let end = SKAction.run{
        print("\(self.counter) -- duration: \(self.duration)")
        guard self.isLoopEnabled else { return } //flag allows you to exit loop
        self.loop() //repeats by calling itself
    }
    
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([ wait, run, end ])
    self.run(sequence, withKey:"loop action")
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    loop()
}
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted. One questions: why do I have to use self.[…] in run?

Comment: not entirely sure the technical reason. something to do with how variables are captured inside closures. sorry don't know more than that